# Installing Cloudera manager on Oracle Linux manually,-FAILED to start

Tags: cloudera-manager

I am trying to install the `CDM-cloudera manager 5.7.x` using the manual `Tarball` method using the following link on a Oracle Linux 6 single node:

[CDM-cloudera manager 5.7.x- manual installation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_c.html)

We opted for manual installation due to space issue in the root drive. so we chose another folder in linux and provided it with all access as mentioned in the link.

After all the necessary configuration, when we start the cloudera-scm-server, it shows up with a `[FAILED]` status, i checked the `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server` and did not find any file created there. the access to this folder(`/var/log/cloudera-scm-server`) has been given rightly as there were other error messages we fixed through the logs generated here.

However as we try to start the `cloudera` manager using the command:

```
sudo -u cloudera-service tarball_root/etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-server start
```

It fails without any details of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check SELinux
2. Check Firewall (and iptables)
3. Check Proxy

If it is not related to above post /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer logs

Comment: ..i did check :( no files generated for the latest run.

Comment: it would help if i could find out as to where in the script it error's out. or other possible traces of the failed run..

Comment: You can check logs in /var/logs/cloudera-manager-installer, there only you can find the details about what went wrong